# AWS RDS migration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

The current setup is the following one:

- MySQL RDS Master InstanceDB with some MyISAM tables in some of its DBs (in default VPC)
- MySQL RDS Read Replica (in default VPC)
- New custom VPC with private subnets created and ready, so that I can    perform the migration to this new custom VPC

1) Stop the traffic towards the RDS DB from the web/app servers

2) Create a manual snapshot of the RDS InstanceDB following this procedure:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html#Overview.BackupDeviceRestrictions
If you want to take a snapshot of your MyISAM tables prior to restoring, follow these steps:

2.1) Stop all activity to your MyISAM tables (that is, close all sessions).
You can close all sessions by calling the `mysql.rds_kill` command for each process that is returned from the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` command.

What about the processes in charge if the replication to the ReadReplica?
[image]

2.2) Lock and flush each of your MyISAM tables. For example, the following commands lock and flush two tables named myisam_table1 and myisam_table2:

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES myisam_table, myisam_table2 WITH READ LOCK;
```

2.3) Take a manual snapshot

2.4) When the snapshot has completed, release the locks and resume activity on the MyISAM tables. You can release the locks on your tables using the following command:

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

These steps force MyISAM to flush data stored in memory to disk thereby ensuring a clean start when you restore from a DB snapshot.

3) Restore from the snapshot and create a new DBInstance in the new custom VPC

4) Alter (user databases) tables to change to InnoDB

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

5) Modify the web/app code (new servers in the custom VPC) to point to the new RDS DBInstance

Any thoughts? Has someone performed a similar procedure?
Should I stop the ReadReplica beforehand?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply creating a new RDS replica of this instance in the new VPC, and then promoting the new replica to be a standalone master?  RDS replicas do not need any connectivity to each other via *your* networking -- they have their own -- so I'm not sure why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Good option! I´ll test it

Comment: not possible... when you select the subnetGroup of the new custom VPC when creating the ReadReplica, it gives an error like this: "The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-xxxx and the EC2 security group is in vpc-yyyy (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone faced the same issue, I followed the procedure above and it worked perfectly.
Just be careful if you assign a Parameter Group to your new RDS and you want to make the change to InnoDB. Make sure the Parameter Group allows that.